# Disable WAR specific cache jBoss GWT

Tags: gwt, jboss, browser-cache

My applications is based on the following:

1. jBoss EAP 5.1
2. GWT

I have created additional war in jBoss/deploy/new.war where I put a lot of .wav files. I play the audio files from the browser using gwt Audio. But, the file is always cached in the browser even if I delete the file from the folder or rename it.

Could anyone tell me as to how I can disable browser caching of .wav files being played via GWT hosted on jBoss EAP 5.1. Note, I have no access to the http requests that gwt uses to play and hence cannot edit the header files. Please help me out !

Comment: Is it static resource on server?

Comment: You could set the no-cache headers using a servlet filter. Is this an option for you? I'm not sure what you mean when you say that you "have no access to the http requests".

Comment: The resource is dynamic on the server.

Comment: What I mean by no access to http requests is that, I use GWT Audio to create an Audio object, which can only take a file that has been hosted on the server ( as WAR ). All I do is call audio.play() and gwt plays audio on the client and hence do not do any httpservlet requests/response.

Answer (score 0):

If the wav files are served by JBoss, you should be able to add no-cache headers using a servlet filter mapped to the `*.wav` pattern, e.g.:

```
@WebFilter("*.wav")
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        httpResponse.setDateHeader("Date", System.currentTimeMillis());
        httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000L);
        httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for java ee 6. I am currrently using the seam framework. But I am trying to find a seam alternative for it.